# Office Toolkit API Support (SOAP v48.0)

Tags: soap-api, office-connect

I'm trying to write some Salesforce integration using the SForceOfficeToolkit 4. I'm using a Sandbox currently with Admin access. I can create an account manually, but I'm getting a lot of errors right off the bat trying to create a simple account:

```
'Set sfAcct to be a new Account Object
Set sfAcct(0) = sfApi.CreateObject("Account")
sfAcct(0)("Name") = "Test1"
'commit the object
Debug.Print ("Createable: " & sfAcct(0).Createable)
sfApi.Create sfAcct, False
'refresh it to get server values
sfApi.Refresh sfAcct, False
Set CreateAccount = sfAcct(0)
```

However, running this code I get the following error:

```
ExceptionCode : 0
Createable: True
CreateAccount Err = Invalid field index::street
ExceptionCode : 5039
```

I've searched fields, tabs, labels, etc. There is no "street" field (BillingStreet and ShippingStreet only.
Can I track the API call that is being made? And why is it giving me an error when only the "Name" field is required? Is the Office Toolkit even supported?
Thank you!